# Header resizes on scroll perfectly, but

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, media

I've set an javascript that checks my current position (Y). And if I've scrolled more than 5px, the header resizes. That's working perfectly, but the main issue is that I would like to cut off/turn off the javascript in a media query. Right now I'm working on making my webpage mobile friendly, but I haven't managed to turn off the javascript. I don't want the header to resize on scroll on smaller devices, and I'm completely lost right now. I've googled, but haven't managed to find anything that could help me..

Here's my HTML for the header.

```
<div class="headerbox">
    <header>

            <div class="Main-Header">
                <h1>header</h1>
            </div>

    </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">alt1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">alt2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">alt3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">alt4</a></li>
            </ul>
     <div class="underline1"></div>
     <div class="underline2"></div>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.headerbox{
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
 }
header{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    width:100%;
    height:8.2vw;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    transition: height 0.3s linear 0s, padding 0.3s linear 0s;
  }

h1{
    font-family:montserrat, "montserrat Medium";
    font-size:4.3vw;
 }
 .Main-Header{
    margin-left: 1vw;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:20vw;
    height: 60%;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.underline1{
    border-top:0.222826vw solid #FFAE00;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-0.51vw;
    box-shadow:#966600 0px 1px;
}
.underline2{
    border-bottom: 0.222826vw solid #FFAE00;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2.7vw;
    box-shadow:#966600 0px -1px;
}
nav
{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}
ul
{
    margin-left:35px;
    font-family:montserrat, "montserrat Medium";
    font-size:1.44837vw;
    letter-spacing:-0.5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:6.5px;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:600;
    line-height:2.0797vw;
}
li{
    float:left;
    width:175px;
}
a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-style:none;
}
```

And lastly, JS

```
var header, nav, adidas, option24, juventus, h1, secheader, yPos;
function yScroll(){
header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
yPos = window.pageYOffset;


if(yPos > 5){
    h1.style.marginTop = "2vw";
    header.style.height = "4.4565vw";
    header.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    nav.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
}
else {

    h1.style.marginTop = "0vw";
    header.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)";
    header.style.height = "8.2vw";
    nav.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)";
}

}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```

Comment: You can check the window width with JS - or just always add the class and then use media queries to determine when those rules are actually applied. Both have their strengths: Build a jsFiddle next time - and leave out the specifics like font-family. https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/8Lconzky/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `window.innerWidth` along with the `yPos` and only apply your JS if both conditions match.

```js
var header, nav, adidas, option24, juventus, h1, secheader, yPos;
function yScroll() {
  header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
  nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
  h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  yPos = window.pageYOffset;
  winWidth = window.innerWidth;

  if (yPos > 5 && winWidth > 600) {
    h1.style.marginTop = "2vw";
    header.style.height = "4.4565vw";
    header.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    nav.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  } else {
    h1.style.marginTop = "0vw";
    header.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)";
    header.style.height = "8.2vw";
    nav.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
}

.headerbox{
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
 }
header{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    width:100%;
    height:8.2vw;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    transition: height 0.3s linear 0s, padding 0.3s linear 0s;
  }

h1{
    font-family:montserrat, "montserrat Medium";
    font-size:4.3vw;
 }
 .Main-Header{
    margin-left: 1vw;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:20vw;
    height: 60%;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.underline1{
    border-top:0.222826vw solid #FFAE00;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-0.51vw;
    box-shadow:#966600 0px 1px;
}
.underline2{
    border-bottom: 0.222826vw solid #FFAE00;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2.7vw;
    box-shadow:#966600 0px -1px;
}
nav
{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}
ul
{
    margin-left:35px;
    font-family:montserrat, "montserrat Medium";
    font-size:1.44837vw;
    letter-spacing:-0.5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:6.5px;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:600;
    line-height:2.0797vw;
}
li{
    float:left;
    width:175px;
}
a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbox">
  <header>

    <div class="Main-Header">
      <h1>header</h1>
    </div>

  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">alt1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">alt2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">alt3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">alt4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="underline1"></div>
    <div class="underline2"></div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to determine the width of the window

`if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use your javascript to add/remove a class, rather than apply the CSS changes directly? You can then media query to your heart's content, and it'll even have a slightly lower overhead for the visitor's machine.

It also has the added benefit of dealing with users resizing their browser window to a mobile size after scrolling.